# getRunningAppProcesses returns empty list on Android L (5.1.1)

Tags: android, process

I just tested my app and CM, ATM Android Assistant, etc. All of them can not get the running process list but they works fine on pre OS version. So what's going on with  Android L (5.1.1)? please help!

```
am = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> list = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
Log.i(TAG, "LQ::examine list.size()=" + list.size());
```

Comment: "So what's going on with Android 5.1.1 Lollipop?" and what's going on with Android 5.1.1 Lollipop? what's the result?

Comment: I cannot get Running Task List on 5.1.1. BUt works fine on pre os version.

Comment: so `getRunningAppProcesses` or `getRunningTasks` ? can you decide what is not working?

Comment: getRunningAppProcesses

Comment: **Note: this method is only intended for debugging**, do you use it for other purposes?

Comment: Check this [difference-between-running-task-and-running-process-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148420/difference-between-running-task-and-running-process-in-android)

Comment: Du Speed Booster & Power Clean uses getRunningServices instead, maybe getRunningAppProcesses is deprecated in future.

Comment: @pskink debugging OR use cases to show the user a UI-ish overview of the running processes- There are legal reasons to use this api!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I decide to use getRunningServices  instead!

Du Speed Booster & Power Clean uses getRunningServices instead, maybe getRunningAppProcesses is deprecated in future.

Thank you google, thank you alphabet.

```
    Hashtable<String, List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo>> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo>>();
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo rsi : am.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (isCanceled()) {
            return;
        }

        String pkgName = rsi.service.getPackageName();
        if (hashtable.get(pkgName) == null) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> list = new ArrayList<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo>();
            list.add(rsi);
            hashtable.put(pkgName, list);
        } else {
            hashtable.get(pkgName).add(rsi);
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    int size =  hashtable.size();
    for (Iterator it = hashtable.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); i++) {
        String key = (String) it.next();
        List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> value = hashtable.get(key);
        ProcessItem item = new ProcessItem(getContext(), value.get(0).pid, key, totalCpu, totalRam);
        if (!whiteList.contains(item.pkgName)) {
            if (!killList.contains(item.pkgName)) {
                killList.add(item.pkgName);
                ramTotal += item.ram;

                if (getListener() != null) {
                    Progress progress = new Progress(this);
                    progress.setArg1(i);
                    progress.setArg2(size);
                    progress.setMsg(item.appName);
                    progress.setObj(item);
                    getListener().onExamining(progress);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    hashtable.clear();
    hashtable = null;
```

Comment: how getRunningServices will return all running app processes? If i am not mistaken it wull return only running services

Comment: @Lester, We are a process killer app like ATK, so we need running things like process or service.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `UsageStatsManager`.

```
UsageStatsManager mUsageStatsManager = (UsageStatsManager)getSystemService(Context.USAGE_STATS_SERVICE);
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long beginTime = endTime - 1000*60;

// We get usage stats for the last minute
List<UsageStats > stats = mUsageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_DAILY, beginTime, endTime);

// Sort the stats by the last time used
if(stats != null) 
{
    SortedMap<Long,UsageStats> mySortedMap = new TreeMap<Long,UsageStats>();
    for (UsageStats usageStats : stats) 
    {
        mySortedMap.put(usageStats.getLastTimeUsed(),usageStats);
    }
    if(mySortedMap != null && !mySortedMap.isEmpty()) 
    {
        topActivity =  mySortedMap.get(mySortedMap.lastKey()).getPackageName();
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, you need `PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` permission.  You can prompt the user to do this by opening the screen in settings:

```
Intent usageAccessIntent = new Intent( Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS );
usageAccessIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
startActivity( usageAccessIntent );
```

Answer (score 1):

I could get foreground app list by using `getRunningServices(`) method on android 6.0. Thanks @thecr0w

```
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); List appProcessInfoList = mActivityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```