# Issues in invoking getRunningAppProcesses() on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android

I try to invoke getRunningAppProcesses() on Android 5.1.1,but it return empty list or a list which only contain my application.But the same codes are running perfectly on Android 5.1 or on pre version.

Do anyone know the reason??Thanks!

```
am = (ActivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> list = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933866/getrunningappprocesses-returns-empty-list-on-android-m5-1-1

Answer (score 1):

I think since Android 5.1.1, Android would like to manage the processes all by himself, so getRunningAppProcesses() has no business with third party applications any more...

Comment: Yes, I change to get services   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933866/getrunningappprocesses-returns-empty-list-on-android-m5-1-1/31936796?noredirect=1#comment52226446_31936796